# how to find matrix nonsingular P and Q such that $PAQ $ is a normal form?

Tags: matrices, self-learning

Given matrix $A$: $$\pmatrix{1&1&1\\2&2&2\\-1&1&-3\\1&2&0}$$

**how to find matrix nonsingular P and Q such that $PAQ $ is a normal form?**

Thanks!

Comment: what flavor of normal form would you like?

Comment: @jagy the normal form for $A=IAI$ and $PAQ=Ir$ with rank=2

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Example

Comment: any other answer?

Comment: You don't just guess $P$ and $Q.$ Elementary row operations, which take your matrix into row echelon form (but all integers!), are accomplished by multiplying on the left by elementary matrices, which are 4 by 4. The  result has a 1 in the upper left. Column operations are accomplished by multiplying on the right by 3 by 3 elementary matrices. $P$ is the product of those used on the left; $Q$ is the product of those used on the right. Order is important! If you kept track properly, your final P and Q should accomplish the whole thing in one go.